# Neo4j multiple cypher queries from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I want to run all these queries into neo4j, I can successfully run one cypher query in session but for multiple queries, it shows error. 
I also need result back in JSON format for individual queries. Any help please?

```
var array=[];
var ftrend= [ '21', '23', '24', '41', '42', '43' ]
console.log("Query for TSB");

for (var j = 0; j<ftrend.length; j++){
    var b=0; var m=0; var t=0;

    for (var i = 0 ; i < 16; i++) {

        t= t+1;
        tbm_id = 'T'+t;
        array.push('MATCH (qck:QuickCheckKriterium {uuid:"' + tbm_id  + '"}),(tsb:Trendsteckbrief {id :"TSB'+ftrend[j]+'"}) return *')

    }


}

console.log(array);
```

//sample result for this query

```
MATCH (qck:QuickCheckKriterium {uuid:"T1"}),(tsb:Trendsteckbrief {id :"TSB21"}) return *',

'MATCH (qck:QuickCheckKriterium {uuid:"T2"}),(tsb:Trendsteckbrief {id :"TSB21"}) return *',

MATCH (qck:QuickCheckKriterium {uuid:"T1"}),(tsb:Trendsteckbrief {id :"TSB23"}) return *',

'MATCH (qck:QuickCheckKriterium {uuid:"T2"}),(tsb:Trendsteckbrief {id :"TSB23"}) return *'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION:

```
console.log(array.join(' UNION '))
```

[ https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/union/ ]